# Object vs Arrays in Javascript is as Python's Dictionaries vs Lists?

Tags: javascript, python, performance

I know in python I can use lists in order to make fast sortings and dictionaries in order to search things faster (because immutable objects can be hashed). Is that the same for javascript too? I haven't seen anything about the performance of datatypes in javascript after much search.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a useful mental model to compare Python dicts with JS objects and Python lists with JS arrays. Technically they might be implemented differently (in particular, the V8 engine doesn't always represent objects as hash tables)

Comment: JavaScript has no real equivalent to Python's maps. The only thing it has that's close is objects - but those can only have string keys. There is no built in way to use a Map and giving hash to different sorts of objects. You have to use a library. Most modern JS runtimes JavaScript are much faster than Python, for example - they'd treat an array like an actual C array when possible.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's not the reason they are faster, though, since Python lists are also implemented as contiguous arrays. The point about string-only keys in objects is probably the key difference I guess (and the JS implementation of objects)

Comment: You should distinguish between language specification and implementation. Implementation, (e.g. cPython, V8 engine) would be the key for performance comparison.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: what's the diff between JS's Map()s (or WeakMaps() ) and Python's maps?

Comment: @dandavis JS maps, at least until ES7 do not support hashes. For example, if you want to use an object as a key, the only equality comparison you get is reference equality meaning you effectively can't use anything other than primitives (number,string,boolean,null,undefined) as ES6 map keys usefully.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum:  interesting. i've always used a private {} as a key to share secrets because it's always fresh. i've found this per-object behavior very useful, especially in caching function calls. are you saying that something that predictably serialized the key object would be more useful?

Comment: @dandavis I'm saying that while they solve some use case, the much more general use case Python maps solve (by allowing tuple hashes for example) is currently not solved at all by ES6 maps. When you say "I've always used a private {} as a key " - do you mean in an ES6 map?

Comment: i mean like "new Map()" in firefox... i'll look into Python's flavor, thanks.

Comment: @NiklasB. JS has a JIT, it's smart enough to make array element access as fast as it is in C, it's not just having the memory contiguous, it's also fast access In 'hot' JS segments that's just a pointer reference away.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Isn't that what I said? That it's not the fact of contiguous memory that makes it fast?

Comment: @NiklasB. No, [as far as I can tell](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) python lists store pointers to python objects, not values contiguously. To actually use any value you need to dereference those pointers which point to different areas in memory. That's going to be painfully slow for numbers.

Comment: @NiklasB. How does boxing integers make an implementation decent? wat. I guess all JavaScript implementations in 2014 are indecent :)

Comment: @Esailija forget what I said, it seems to hold for Ruby but not cpython. By boxing I meant that you have a union-type for pointers and integers, but probably it's the wrong term

Answer (score 2):

Yes. "Object vs Arrays in Javascript is as Python's Dictionaries vs Lists".
Performance pros and cons are also the same. With lists being more efficient if numeric indexes are appropriate to the task and dictionaries being more efficient for long lists that must be accessed by a string.

```
var dict = {};
dict['apple'] = "a sweet edible fruit";
dict['boy'] = "a young male human";

var list = [];
list.push("apples");
list.push("oranges");
list.push("pears");
```

Comment: The title may have fooled you, if you read my question you will understand I don't ask for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for some bibliography and other sources that could answer this question. I Know that this isn't the best answer, but let me try an answer that involve some concepts that lend us to discuss this topic.

## Javascript and inheritance

Although the it could suggest that arrays and objects in javascript are like lists and dictionaries, they are different because each language are written in different ways, with different underlying philosophies, concepts and purposes.

In the case of Javascript, it seems that both Arryas and Objects are more like hash tables. Contrary to the intuition, Arrays are just an other type of built in object of javascript. In fact, as they say in the [ECMAScript Specification 6.1.7](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-object-type)

> #### The Object Type
>
> An Object is logically a collection of properties. Each property is
>   either a data property, or an accessor property:
>
> A data property associates a key value with an ECMAScript language
>   value and a set of Boolean attributes. An accessor property associates
>   a key value with one or two accessor functions, and a set of Boolean
>   attributes. The accessor functions are used to store or retrieve an
>   ECMAScript language value that is associated with the property.
>   Properties are identified using key values. A property key value is
>   either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. All String and
>   Symbol values, including the empty string, are valid as property keys.
>   A property name is a property key that is a String value.
>
> An integer index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical
>   numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a
>   positive integer ≤ 253 - 1. An array index is an integer index whose
>   numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 232 - 1.
>
> Property keys are used to access properties and their values. There
>   are two kinds of access for properties: get and set, corresponding to
>   value retrieval and assignment, respectively. The properties
>   accessible via get and set access includes both own properties that
>   are a direct part of an object and inherited properties which are
>   provided by another associated object via a property inheritance
>   relationship. Inherited properties may be either own or inherited
>   properties of the associated object. Each own property of an object
>   must each have a key value that is distinct from the key values of the
>   other own properties of that object.

And,[about the arrays](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array-objects), it specifies:

> #### 22.1Array Objects
>
> Array objects are exotic objects that give special treatment to a certain class of property names.

Following the logic above, and as it says in the specification, the language was thinked in such way that all types in javascript extends a global object, and then new methods and properties are added to have differents behaivors.

### Memory Management

There are a gap between the language specifications and how they must be implemented in an actual runtime enviroment. Altought each implementation has its own logics, it seems that most of them has similarities.

As [This Article Explains](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-inside-the-v8-engine-5-tips-on-how-to-write-optimized-code-ac089e62b12e):

> Most JavaScript interpreters use dictionary-like structures (hash
>   function based) to store the location of object property values in the
>   memory. This structure makes retrieving the value of a property in
>   JavaScript more computationally expensive than it would be in a
>   non-dynamic programming language like Java or C#. In Java, all of the
>   object properties are determined by a fixed object layout before
>   compilation and cannot be dynamically added or removed at runtime
>   (well, C# has the dynamic type which is another topic). As a result,
>   the values of properties (or pointers to those properties) can be
>   stored as a continuous buffer in the memory with a fixed-offset
>   between each. The length of an offset can easily be determined based
>   on the property type, whereas this is not possible in JavaScript where
>   a property type can change during runtime.

As this make javascript kind of ineffitient, the engineers had to came with some clever workarounds in order to solve this problem. Following [this other article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shapes-ics):

> If you access a property, e.g. object.y, the JavaScript engine looks
>   in the JSObject for the key 'y', then loads the corresponding property
>   attributes, and finally returns the [[Value]].
>
> But where are these property attributes stored in memory? Should we
>   store them as part of the JSObject? If we assume that we’ll be seeing
>   more objects with this shape later, then it’s wasteful to store the
>   full dictionary containing the property names and attributes on the
>   JSObject itself, as the property names are repeated for all objects
>   with the same shape. That’s a lot of duplication and unnecessarily
>   memory usage. As an optimization, engines store the Shape of the
>   object separately.
>
> This Shape contains all the property names and the attributes, except
>   for their [[Value]]s. Instead the Shape contains the offset of the
>   values inside of the JSObject, so that the JavaScript engine knows
>   where to find the values. Every JSObject with this same shape points
>   to exactly this Shape instance. Now every JSObject only has to store
>   the values that are unique to this object.
>
> The benefit becomes clear when we have multiple objects. No matter how
>   many objects there are, as long as they have the same shape, we only
>   have to store the shape and property information once!
>
> All JavaScript engines use shapes as an optimization, but they don’t
>   all call them shapes:
>
> - Academic papers call them Hidden Classes (confusing w.r.t. JavaScript classes)
> - V8 calls them Maps (confusing w.r.t. JavaScript Maps)
> - Chakra calls them Types (confusing w.r.t. JavaScript’s dynamic types and typeof)
> - JavaScriptCore calls them Structures
>     *SpiderMonkey calls them Shapes

## Python

### Arrays

Python uses a different aproach for the implementation of lists, it seems that lists are more like some dynamics arrays than an actual array that you could find in C, But they are sill are focussed on saving spaces of time and complexity in a runtime. [As this FAQ cited form the PyDocs says](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-are-lists-implemented.htm):

> Python’s list objects are really variable-length arrays, not
>   Lisp-style linked lists. The implementation uses a contiguous array of
>   references to other objects, and keeps a pointer to this array and the
>   array’s length in a list head structure.
>
> This makes indexing a list (L[i]) an operation whose cost is
>   independent of the size of the list or the value of the index.
>
> When items are appended or inserted, the array of references is
>   resized. Some cleverness is applied to improve the performance of
>   appending items repeatedly; when the array must be grown, some extra
>   space is allocated so the next few times don’t require an actual
>   resize.

Like javascript, Python's lists are not required to be homogeneous, so they are not an actual implementation of other "strong typed" data structures that does have to contain only the same entities such as integers, strings, etc.

Same as javascript, the specifications of the language the actual implementation are two separate things. Depending on if you are using Cpython, Jython, IronPython, etc, the memory management and the actual functions that runs behind the scenes will be making diferent things in the process of interpreting python to machine code.

I know that this isnt the best source, but [as I found discussed in Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-are-Python-lists-implemented-internally):

> Contrary to what their name implies, Python lists are actually arrays(...).
>   Specifically, they are dynamic arrays with exponential
>   over-allocation, which allows code like the following to have linear
>   complexity:
>
> ```
> lst = []
> for i in xrange(0, 100000):
>     lst.append(i)
> ```
>
> Alternative implementations like Jython and IronPython seem to use
>   whatever native dynamic array class their underlying language
>   (respectively Java and C#) provides, so they have the same performance
>   characteristics (the precise underlying classes seem to be ArrayList
>   for Jython and C# List for IronPython).
>
> (...)arrays technically store pointers rather than the objects
>   themselves, which allows the array to contain only elements of a
>   specific size. Having pointers all over the place in the underlying
>   implementation is a common feature of dynamically typed languages, and
>   in fact of any language that tries to pretend it doesn't have
>   pointers.

### Dictionaries

As the official docs puts in their ["History and Design FAQ"](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-dictionaries-implemented-in-cpython)

> CPython’s dictionaries are implemented as resizable hash tables.
>   Compared to B-trees, this gives better performance for lookup (the
>   most common operation by far) under most circumstances, and the
>   implementation is simpler.
>
> Dictionaries work by computing a hash code for each key stored in the
>   dictionary using the hash() built-in function. The hash code varies
>   widely depending on the key; for example, “Python” hashes to
>   -539294296 while “python”, a string that differs by a single bit, hashes to 1142331976. The hash code is then used to calculate a
>   location in an internal array where the value will be stored. Assuming
>   that you’re storing keys that all have different hash values, this
>   means that dictionaries take constant time – O(1), in computer science
>   notation – to retrieve a key. It also means that no sorted order of
>   the keys is maintained, and traversing the array as the .keys() and
>   .items() do will output the dictionary’s content in some arbitrary
>   jumbled order.

## In Conclution

There are two separate things about a language: one involves how it should work, with it syntax, semantics, logic and philosophy. On the other hand you have the actual implementation of that language in a specific runtime, interpreter or compilation.
This way, although (in theory) you have one Python or one Javascript, you could have CPython, IronPython Jython, etc; and in the other hand, you have SpiderMonkey, V8, etc.

But referring to how each runtime implements the language features of Arrays/Lists and Objects/Dictionaries and how analogous they are, it seems that Javascript has chosen a inheritance model based on prototypes that makes everithing a kind of object; so both Objects and Dictionaries are more like a hash table than an actual array.
On the other hand, Python has a more flavores in respect of data structures, both in their libraries and in how the interpreters deal with them, making use of arrays or dynamic arrays to bring to life the Pyton's Lists, and using hash tables for the dictionaries, making them more similar to the objects in javascript.

Comment: This is very misleading w.r.t. JavaScript.

Comment: I would rather hide the answer and keep researching?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t realize that posted. It was supposed to have details. Specifically, that JavaScript arrays will be implemented as you’d expect on every reasonable engine, including the ones of all major browsers today, when you use array index properties: not with a hash table, but with sequential memory. (Like a Python list.)

Comment: I posted the answer above in order to start a discussion about how the languages differ, and how their runtimes deal with the data structures that they offer, because the original question was tricky. But, yes, it seems to be some complex stuff and maybe I oversimplified the dark magic that may ocur behind the scenes.

Comment: Looking this almost three years later, I cant believe I worte such a incoherent answer.

Comment: Please, stop upvoting. I think this isn't the best answer.